# Getting hightest and lowest points

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have GeoJSON files that contains altitude values. I have used these GeoJSON files to be shown on leaflet.js web map.
I need to show values of highest and lowest point in two divs when I clicking on each line.
Here is my code that to show GeoJSON lines on the map:

```
$.getJSON('data/routes/New/Lwn.geojson', function (collection) {
    Lwn = L.geoJson(collection, {
      'style': function () {
        return {
          'color': '#0000FF',
          'weight': 3,
          'opacity': 0
        }
      }, onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on('click', function(e) {
          showElevation(e.target);
        })
        layer.on('mousedown', function() {
          layer.setStyle({color: '#FFFF00', opacity: 1});
        })
        layer.on('mouseup', function() {
          Lwn.resetStyle(layer);
        })
      }
    }).on('click', function (e) {
      $('#overlay').slideDown();
      $('#Name').html("Name: "+'<strong>'+e.layer.feature.properties.name+'</strong>');
      $('#Distance').html("Distance: "+'<strong>'+e.layer.feature.properties.Lwn_length+'</strong>'+" Meters");
      $('#Surface').html("Surface: "+'<strong>'+e.layer.feature.properties.surface+'</strong>');
      $('#Route-Symbol').show();
      document.getElementById('Route-Symbol').src = `https://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/api/symbols?osmc:symbol=${e.layer.feature.properties.imgSource}` 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function `showElevation(e.target)` has first to find points with min and max height, you first define two simple functions for finding points with min and max height in array of point coordinates (each point has structure [x, y, z]) (courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript):

```
function minHPoint(arr, multi) {
  var min = Infinity, len, tmpArr, minPoint;
  if (multi) {
    multiLen = arr.length;
    }
  else {
    tmpArr = arr;
    multiLen = 0;
  };
  while (multiLen--) {
    if (multiLen >= 0) tmpArr = arr[multiLen];
    len = tmpArr.length;
    while (len--) {
      if (tmpArr[len][2] < min) {
        min = tmpArr[len][2];
        minPoint = tmpArr[len];
      }
    }
  }
  return minPoint;
};

function maxHPoint(arr, multi) {
  var max = -Infinity, len, tmpArr, maxPoint;
  if (multi) {
    multiLen = arr.length;
    }
  else {
    tmpArr = arr;
    multiLen = 0;
  };
  while (multiLen--) {
    if (multiLen >= 0) tmpArr = arr[multiLen];
    len = tmpArr.length;
    while (len--) {
      if (tmpArr[len][2] > max) {
        max = tmpArr[len][2];
        maxPoint = tmpArr[len];
      }
    }
  }
  return maxPoint;
};
```

Then use those functions in your `showElevation(e.target)` function:

```
function showElevation(layer) {
  var coords = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates;
  var minPoint = minHPoint(coords, (layer.feature.geometry.type == 'MultiLineString'));
  var maxPoint = maxHPoint(coords, (layer.feature.geometry.type == 'MultiLineString'));
  .... 
  (code for displaying min and max height)
  ....
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and response.
I just need to know which variable that i will use to show values
$('#High-Point').html("Hight point: "+???);

Comment: I assumed from your question that you need just min height (`minH`) and max height (`maxH`) values. Do you need also coordinates of those points?

Comment: Yes, coordinates are in the GeoJSON file.
but i have used variables of minH and maxH, but it shows (-Infinity, and -Infinity)

Comment: Answer is modified to give point coordinates, not only heights.

Comment: I have used the new function and i have used variable of maxPoint for showing the highest Z values on the div , but it returns strange result (many many coordinates).

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your geojson file. Can you provide it?

Comment: Here is the GeoJSON file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqqp2hnk6hfqg0x/Nwn.rar?dl=0

Comment: Your geojson objects have `MultiLineString` geometry. I modified the code. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but returns [lat, long, Z] while i only need Z value.

Comment: More is better then less. Then just extract Z from point: `minH = minPoint[2]` and `maxH = maxPoint[2]`.

Comment: Many Thanks, it works now.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Now i need to get max/min Z values from LineString GeoJSON, could you please show me the code before editing it to be on MultiLineString? 

i have created a new question for this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314546/looping-on-geojson-to-get-maximum-minimum-altitude

@TomazicM

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like your line already has the highest and lowest values as attributes. try something like this.

In one of the div's put a span tag    the other put one with an id="lowest"

Next in the onEachFeature function

```
layer.on('click' function(e){
    $("#highest").val(e.target.feature.properties.high);
    $("#lowest").val(e.target.feature.properties.low);
```

That will read your lines attributes and place their values in the span tag, in your div.

Comment: I just have Z values, i need to create a function to get Max and Mix values from these values.
this my GeoJSON look like:
     "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12.913651374,
              47.724617696,
              535.607
            ],
            [
              12.9146569,
              47.7244117,
              541.91
            ],
            [
              12.9153843,
              47.7239533,

it is a MultiLineString GeoJSON file, i think it contains 3 arrays.

Comment: The third value is Z.  var z = e.target.feature.geometry.coordinates[2]; but you will need a function to determine the highest and lowest.

Comment: @BillChappell Already answered before your comment.